# Assign a Variable to a Loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
for names in city_names:
    iteration_count += 1
    print(iteration_count, names)
```

I am trying to set the result of this loop equal to a variable, how would I proceed in doing so?

Here is the list I am using in the loop:

```
city_names = ['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls']
```

Comment: This would be very bad Python. Also what would be the content of this new variable?

Comment: "result of this loop" what is the result of this loop?

Comment: Can that solve what you want to do: ```var = zip(city_names, range(len(city_names)))``` ?

Comment: 1 Buenos Aires
2 Toronto
3 Marakesh
4 Albuquerque
5 Los Cabos
6 Greenville
7 Archipelago Sea
8 Pyeongchang
9 Walla Walla Valley
10 Salina Island
11 Solta
12 Iguazu Falls

Comment: Like this: `result = list(enumerate(city_names, start=1))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 city_names = ['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls']

 result = ''
 iteration_count = 1
 for names in city_names:    
    result = result + str(iteration_count) + ' ' + names + ' '
    iteration_count += 1
 print (result)
```

Result is as you wanted it to be:

```
1 Buenos Aires 2 Toronto 3 Marakesh 4 Albuquerque 5 Los Cabos 6 Greenville 7 Archipelago Sea 8 Pyeongchang 9 Walla Walla Valley 10 Salina Island 11 Solta 12 Iguazu Falls
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.join` method with a generator expression that iterates through the `enumerate` generator that outputs `city_names` with a counter:

```
output = ''.join(f'{count} {name}\n' for count, name in enumerate(city_names, 1))
```

`output` becomes:

```
1 Buenos Aires
2 Toronto
3 Marakesh
4 Albuquerque
5 Los Cabos
6 Greenville
7 Archipelago Sea
8 Pyeongchang
9 Walla Walla Valley
10 Salina Island
11 Solta
12 Iguazu Falls
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, to capture what gets printed to the standard output into a variable, you can temporarily override `sys.stdout` with a `StringIO` object using the `unittest.mock.patch` method as a context manager:

```
from io import StringIO
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('sys.stdout', new=StringIO()) as output:
    iteration_count = 0
    for names in city_names:
        iteration_count += 1
        print(iteration_count, names)
print(output.getvalue())
```

This outputs:

```
1 Buenos Aires
2 Toronto
3 Marakesh
4 Albuquerque
5 Los Cabos
6 Greenville
7 Archipelago Sea
8 Pyeongchang
9 Walla Walla Valley
10 Salina Island
11 Solta
12 Iguazu Falls
```